# How to disable keyboard in a PyCharm project window?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to use search, undo, delete etc. using keyboard in my main editor window and NEVER on my project window.

But once I click file in the project window, I must now do second click into the editor, otherwise my keyboard will start wreaking havoc in the filesystem.

Please tell me there is an intelligent way to disable this!
Could not find it myself, mostly because I don't know how to even name this behaviour.

Comment: Disable what? This sounds like standard application behavior, where opening a thing doesn't necessarily take keyboard focus into that thing and you have to do it manually. In this particular case, maybe you want to open _multiple_ files, so having the application automatically kick you over to the new file would be disruptive.

Comment: I disagree, If I click on a file entry to open file in the editor, nothing stops me from clicking the next one. But the focus for keyboard should be on the last opened file, until I moved it back to the file tree. Because it is the file I am after, and not the tree.

Normally, applications behave exactly like that – they transfer keyboard focus to newly opened file. Examples: sublime text, textmate, msvs

Comment: Just press `Esc` -- it will take focus back to the Editor. It's a default shortcut for the "Focus Editor" action on most keymaps.